# Android NativeActivity open browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, android-ndk, native-activity

I'm looking for a way of opening the browser to "www.google.com" from the inside of an android native activity. I'm aware that there is not an easy way to generate intents from the native code, but according to [this post](http://vkswtips.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/android-how-to-call-java-activity-using.html), it's possible to do it with JNI.

As it's a reasonably common thing, opening a web browser, I'm hoping someone has already figured out how and is willing to share.

Thank you for your help,

Jaime

Comment: what's the problem? Just create JNI function, that will call another function in your activity and call inside it "YouActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com")));"

Comment: So it is 2020 and sending Intents natively is still not supported? @BoJIHanpocmombI JNI can not be used because Java Runtime is not present in native applications.